# Weird letter shift in filename in composer / symfony ApcClassLoader autoload (bit flip?)

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, autoload, apc

I have a really weird bug and I hope someone has experienced anything like this or has an idea to help me.

We have a Symfony application running on a virtualised cluster.

Now for the third time in about half a year we had this really weird bug:

Server stops working with a 500 error, when I search our log the reason is that the autoloader wants to load a file, but there is a one letter shift in the filename:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/View/ChoicdListView.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcClassLoader.php line 112
```

So instead of Choic**e**ListView.php it tried to load Choic**d**ListView.php

Today this happened:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Event/LifecycleEuentArgs.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')" at /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ApcClassLoader.php line 112
```

LifecycleE**u**entArgs.php instead of LifecycleE**v**entArgs.php

- OS is Ubuntu 16.04
- File system is Ext4 on a virtual machine
- Every time this happened nobody deployed anything on the server or was even logged in with SSH (last deploy was over two weeks ago, the server was running the whole time)
- Every time this happened the problem was in the /vendor folder
- Every time one letter was switched to the next or previous letter (N instead of M or U instead of V)
- I searched all files in the entire /var/cache folder in the symfony project for the name of the file but didn't find it
- I didn't find the composer autoload cache file fast enough, so I did **not** check that file.
- Every time only a single machine in the cluster was affected, but it was different machines every time.
- The bug is fixed by deploying again until a couple of months later the bug will happen with a different file.
- The bug only every happened on our production cluster and is not reproducable

So to sum it up, every couple of months Symfony tries to load a file with the wrong file name, only on a single machine in a cluster that nobody touched.

Has anybody any idea what this could be? I doubt this is a symfony problem, could it be a hardware fault? Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Sounds to me like corrupted hardware especially if there is no change happened in this time. Maybe a limit is reached after a time? No empty disk space? Bad Memory?

Comment: Do you have ECC memory on these servers?

Comment: @rob006 I have no idea, I will call the data center and check. All we see is a virtual server.

Comment: @jimpanse There is enough empty disk space, I'll try a memory checker program.